# PHP code shows after HTML code

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I got a php code that shows the table of the contents of my database but I was wondering why it get showed after the html code of the footer when in my code is actually written before. This happen only if I use mysqli and not mysql method to connect to the database.

```
      <div class="1">
        <div class="2">
          <div class="3">  



    <?php
$db = new mysqli('...', '...', '...', '...');
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `...`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

echo "<table class='table'>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    echo "<tr class='info'>
                <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>

                </tr>";  
}

?>
  </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
          <hr>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; HTML CODE HERE</p>
      </footer>
```

Comment: "What is wrong with this code I'm not showing to you"

Comment: I dont get what you mean but thanks for reply.

Comment: We can't help you fix your code if you don't show it to us.

Comment: The code php is perfectly working, i just dont get why it get diplays after the footer. thats it. But ok here is the code. I just wondering why the table get diplayed after the footer and not before.

Comment: Your problem is that there is no `</table>` end tag so the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Correct is missing echo "</table>"; thank you

Comment: Glad you solved the problem, but next time please show *complete* code from the start. If you're having a problem that you don't know how to solve then by definition you can't know what part of the code is "perfectly working" and what is not.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Sure I am gonna do that. Thank for the fast reply.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`</table>` tag is missing in the html you echo from php.

Echo this tag after the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

table end tag missed.

```
<div class="1">
     <div class="2">
     <div class="3">  

        <?php
        $db = new mysqli('...', '...', '...', '...');
        if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
        }

        $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `...`
        SQL;

        if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
            die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
        }

        echo "<table class='table'>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<tr class='info'>
                    <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>

                    </tr>";  
    }

    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer> <p>&copy; HTML CODE HERE</p></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

is missing

```
 echo "</table>";
```

after the while cicle